# No precision specified for (float), WebGL

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, webgl

I was looking into WebGL, and, to see if my system supported it, I went to [this test page](https://code.google.com/p/mivankovic-blog/wiki/WebGLTestpage) to see what happened. Unfortunately, I get an error that says "ERROR: 0:2: '' : No precision specified for (float)". Is this a limitation of my hardware, or do I need to install a different driver, or something?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, on an Asus A52F. My graphics card is a Intel Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2, or at least that's what it says when I run "Details". Under Details/Graphics, the field called "Driver" displays the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a limitation of your hardware, but relates to no precision having been set for the float data type in the shader. See http://code.google.com/p/glsl-unit/issues/detail?id=9

It's entirely possible that WebGL works for you. Have a look at the demos from http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Demo_Repository